# JavaFX MVC MVP connections

Tags: user-interface, model-view-controller, javafx

UPDATE

Along my path to learning JavaFX I have set myself the goal of implementing a GUI similar to SceneBuilder. I have read lots about MVC and MVP plus lots of other schemes. The difference between block diagrams and actual Java code is still huge for me.

My current attempt has a MainController which sets the stage and loads all five panels of a BorderPane. Each of these panels has its own separate xxxView.fxml
as well as a controller. Those panel controllers are declared global in the MainController.

```
....
private StatusbarController statusbar; 

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

    initRootLayout();

    showToolbar();
    showDesignPane();
    showInspector();
    showStatusbar();
}
```

Then I implement the links between the controllers. For example the mouse position from the designPane is shown in the statusbar:

```
public void showDesignPane() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainController.class.getResource("views/DesignPaneView.fxml"));
        designPane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(designPane);

        designPane.setOnMouseMoved((MouseEvent event) -> {
          statusbar.setMousXY(event.getX(), event.getY());
    });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the StatusbarController this is then bound to a TextField textProperty().

Similarly for a newly created node in the designPane, the layoutX value shows in the inspectorPanel on the right. This value however needs to be bi-directional i.e when a layoutX value is entered in the inspector panel, it should update the node's layout in the designPane. But that's where I'm stuck:

How do I implement this bi-directional controller link? Getting an instance of the MainController passed to the InspectorController seems similar to a 'circular declaration'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several more hours of 'research', I have come to the conclusion that trying create this project from scratch is like re-inventing the wheel. That's obviously why frameworks were invented. Hence I have decided to embark on another learning curve and learn about JaxaFX frameworks. Looks like the DEMUX framework is an option because it has lots of documentation - something some of the other frameworks appear to be lacking (probably because they aim at an experience level much higher than mine). For anyone starting their climb from the bottom of the mountain, a mountain guide (= documentation) is critical.

UPDATE: tried to create a Maven project with DEMUX, but cannot even get past:
Fail: Property demuxFrameworkVersion is missing
As I have no clue where to find that version value, it's now off to the next framework. I suspect there is a veeery long road ahead.

FINAL UPDATE found 'Afterburner.fx' and now use it. It's great with a very short learning curve. Watch the videos on the website particularly the last one (ignore the little Google glitch at the start): http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/